# Retrofit and SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, retrofit2

I have an app that i want to have offline functionality, i used retrofit which currently handles the networking for json displays in a listview via a Dataadapter, and I have created a databasehandler to create sqlitedata for data to be stored.

Two Questions:
1. How do i save the data after my retrofit service call has successfully got the data?

2. How do i load data from data if no connect/network available?

I have looked all over but seen no tutorials or any useful answers for retrofit with sqlite?

POJO Class

```
public class Datum implements Serializable
{

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("sku")
    @Expose
    private String sku;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;


    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("list_price")
    @Expose
    private String listPrice;
}
```

SQLDATABASE

```
public class SQLLiteDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Gousto Products";
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "Products";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String KEY_LIST_PRICE = "listPrice";

    public SQLLiteDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " STRING PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LIST_PRICE + " TEXT," + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new
    public void addProduct(Datum product) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, product.getTitle()); // title
        values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, product.getDescription()); // description
        values.put(KEY_LIST_PRICE, product.getListPrice()); //listprice

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single
    Datum getProduct(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_LIST_PRICE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        assert cursor != null;
        Datum product = new Datum(cursor.getString(0),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
        // return
        return product;
    }

    // Getting All
    public List<Datum> getAllProducts() {
        List<Datum> productList = new ArrayList<Datum>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Datum product = new Datum();
                product.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                product.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                product.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
                product.setListPrice(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding  to list
                productList.add(product);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return  list
        return productList;
    }

    // Updating single
    public int updateProduct(Datum product) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, product.getTitle()); // title
        values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, product.getDescription()); // description
        values.put(KEY_LIST_PRICE, product.getListPrice()); //listprice

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_PRODUCTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(product.getId()) });
    }

    // Getting  Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
}
```

MainActivty

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private List<Datum> productList;
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter;

    SQLLiteDatabaseHandler db = new SQLLiteDatabaseHandler(this);




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();
        loadJson();


    }




    private void initViews(){

        productList = new ArrayList<>();

        /**
         * Getting List and then set Adapter
         */

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productListView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



                //Convert Image to byte Array
                String strImage = productList.get(position).getImages().get500().getSrc();


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageView", strImage);
                intent.putExtra("description", productList.get(position).getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("price",  "£ " + productList.get(position).getListPrice());
                intent.putExtra("title", productList.get(position).getTitle());
                try {
                    intent.putExtra("category", "Category: " + productList.get(position).getCategories().get(position).getTitle());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    private void loadJson() {

        final ProgressDialog dialog;
        /**
         * Progress Dialog for User Interaction
         */
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialogTitle));
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialogMessage));
        dialog.show();

        ApiInterface api = RetroClient.getApiService();

        Call<GustoProducts> call = api.getProductList();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<GustoProducts>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GustoProducts> call, Response<GustoProducts> response) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                if (response.isSuccessful()){

                    /**
                     * Got Data successfully
                     */
                    productList = response.body().getData();

                    dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
                    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GustoProducts> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }



}
```

Comment: Use this(https://github.com/clrvynt/android-offline) library, might be helpfull

Comment: Create a table as per your pojo class in your SQLite DB, then as soon as you get response from server, update the data in your SQLite DB. For fetching local data, before making any network call, check if network connectivity is available, if its not available then fetch data from SQLite and load it in your views

Comment: have you got an example of this, as i am this question, i seen it with static dat but with actual dynamic data there are no real tutorials @arshad. A Coding example that is applicable would be good

Comment: Take a look on [RetrofitLoadersSample](https://github.com/ArturVasilov/RetrofitLoadersSample).

Answer (score 0):

```js
Call<Datum> call = api.getProductList();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Datum>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Datum> call, Response<Datum> response) {
if(!response.isSuccessful()){
System.err.println(response.code());
return;
}
List<Datum> listmyproducts =null;
listmyproducts =response.body();
foreach(Datum myproduct : listmyproducts)
{
if(!db.findProduct(myproduct.getProductid())
db.addProduct(myproduct);
else
db.updateProduct(myproduct);
}


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Datum> call, Throwable t) {
System.err.println(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Then move logic of lisview adapter to interview your list will always be empty if the network request fails

```js
private void initViews(){

        productList = new ArrayList<>();

        /**
         * Getting List and then set Adapter
         */
productList = db.getAllProducts();
dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList); listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productListView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



                //Convert Image to byte Array
                 String strImage = productList.get(position).getImages().get500().getSrc();


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageView", strImage);
                intent.putExtra("description", productList.get(position).getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("price",  "£ " + productList.get(position).getListPrice());
                intent.putExtra("title", productList.get(position).getTitle());
                try {
                    intent.putExtra("category", "Category: " + productList.get(position).getCategories().get(position).getTitle());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Now in Main under on create..

```js
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

InitViews();//Load offline local sqlite db data
if(isConnected())//implement network connectivity test .
       {
loadJson();//Refresh db data from retrofit network activiity
}
}....
```